# Is there a list of interned in 2-4 Rosenstrasse?

Tags: germany, world-war-2, jewish, berlin

My Great Uncle Siegfried was a German Jew married to a German (Vera).  They lived in Berlin and survived World War 2.

On February 27 1943, the SS instigated the Final Roundup of Jews in Berlin. Those who were intermarried were interned in 2-4 Rosenstrasse.

Their wives staged a demonstration which successfully led to the release of these intermarried Jews.  How could I find a list of those interned in Rosenstrasse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In looking for the answer to this I saw noted several times that there is not a ton of documentation of the Rosenstrasse / Rosenstraße event that survived the war and there is limited resources that might list names. I was unable to find a 'complete' list.

Nathan Stolzfus seems to be the most cited author on Rosenstrasse and two of his works have popped out that mention specific individuals, but there is no indication any complete list exists in them. If you review the works below and do not find what you are looking for, the author is still living and you may be able to reach out to him and ask the specific question if he is aware of a 'complete list'.

Primary Sources for the Event I was able to locate that specifically list participants are:

The Wiener Library
[This Collection](http://www.wienerlibrary.co.uk/Search-document-collection?item=599)
"Frames 1-95: Copy reports and correspondence from participants in the Rosenstrasse Protest, Berlin 1943 and the 'Sovjet-Paradies Aktion', Berlin 1942- Frame 6 includes a list of the members of the 'Baum Gruppe' who were executed."

Nathan Stoltzfus, [Resistance of the Heart: Intermarriage and the Rosenstraße Protest in Nazi Germany (New York: W.W. Norton, 1996)](http://amzn.to/1SM8OUy). Per the [table of contents](https://books.google.com/books/about/Resistance_of_the_Heart.html?id=EdGtnp24BhwC&hl=en) it does not appear to contain a complete list of individuals and does have many individuals named in it. ISBN-13: 978-0813529097

There is also [another publication by Stoltzfus](http://www.berghahnbooks.com/title.php?rowtag=StoltzfusProtest) "PROTEST IN HITLER'S NATIONAL COMMUNITY" has translated German documents in the Appendix; specifically mentioned regarding the transfer of mixed marriage individuals to be used as labor.  I have not looked at them myself but something to look into as well.

This PHD student paper by [Hilary Jane Potter](http://opus.bath.ac.uk/41221/1/Post_viva_PhD_The_Dynamics_of_German_Remembering_The_Rosenstrasse_Protest_in_Historical_Debate_and_Cultural_Representation.pdf) also has several other smaller sources at the end of the paper to possibly investigate.

I have seen this book referenced a couple times in references to the event but does not seem to be what you are looking for as its focuses on peaceful protest more than the individuals
Wolf Gruner, Widerstand in der Rosenstraße: Die Fabrik-Aktion und die Verfolgung der “Mischehen,” 1943 (Frankfurt am Main: Fischer Taschenbuch Verlag, 2005).
English: *"Resistance in Rosenstrasse: The factory-action and the pursuit of mixed marriages."*

Some of these publications are expensive or have limited availability, but check your local library to see if they have a copy or can obtain a copy or pages via inter-library loan.  Alternatively you can hire a researcher (genealogical or general) to go through the material at a location it is available and search for a specific name.